# nunit-console /runlist does not run certain test's in a list containing parameterized test cases

Tags: powershell, nunit-console, parameterized-unit-test

When running from Powershell with the following command

> **& "c:\Program Files (x86)\Nunit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe" /runlist=C:.....\ReRunTests.txt
>   "C:.....\bin\debug\Web.Test.UI.dll"**

and the following run list
**ReRunTests.txt**

> AddToCartFeature.AddOneItemToMyCart
>   AddToCartFeature.AddPremierToBasket
>   DeliveryOptionsWithANonRegisteredUserFeature.SelectNamedDayDeliveryOption
>   DeliveryOptionsWithANonRegisteredUserFeature.SelectNextDayDeliveryOption
>   DeliveryOptionsWithANonRegisteredUserFeature.SelectPremierDeliveryOption
>   DeliveryOptionsWithANonRegisteredUserFeature.SelectStandardAndReturnsLabelDeliveryOption
>   DeliveryOptionsWithANonRegisteredUserFeature.SelectStandardDeliveryOption
>   UseAlternativeDeliveryAddressOnCheckoutFeature.AddValidAlternativeAddress
>   SubmitFreeTextSearchForExistingProducts("jeans","02/fts/?search=jeans",null)
>   **CreateNewAccountFeature.AnonymousUserWithoutAnExistingAccount** EditMyAccountDetailsFeature.EditExistingCustomerDetails
>   ViewMyAccountDetailsFeature.ViewingCardHolderAddress
>   RefineProductListByParametersFeature.SortByPercentageSavingAndGoToTheSecondPage
>   **TopNavSearchFeature.UsingDropDownNavigation("Mens","MensNewIn","01/mens/new",null)
>   TopNavSearchFeature.UsingDropDownNavigation("Womens","WomensNewIn","01/womens/new",null)**

The tests highlighted in bold are skipped.  It seems like something related to escaping quotes or commas but I can't understand why this one would run

> SubmitFreeTextSearchForExistingProducts("jeans","02/fts/?search=jeans",null)

and the following non-parameterized one does run.

I have tried escaping the quotes, but then the test doesn't run at all.

Comment: What does this have to do with PowerShell, exactly?  Does the command work properly when run from `cmd.exe` or something?

Comment: It's not exactly a PowerShell issue, although I am running the command through PowerShell.  The same happens when run from cmd.exe